# Do I need output gamma correction in a fragment shader?

Tags: opengl, glsl, fragment-shader, color-space

When I *output* a color via `fragColor` in the `main()` function of a fragment shader, are the color component intensities interpreted as linear RGB or sRGB? Or to put it differently, do I have to perform gamma correction in my shader or is this already being taken care of?

If there is no general answer but depends on some OpenGL property: How do I set this property?

To avoid misunderstanding: The respective color has been entirely programmatically generated, there are no textures or the like (which may necessitate *input* gamma correction).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every fragment shader output is routed to a specific image in the framebuffer ([based on `glDrawBuffers` state](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Framebuffer_Draw_Buffer)). That image has a format. That format defines the default colorspace interpretation of the corresponding output.

Therefore, if you are writing a value to an image in a linear RGB format, then the system will interpret that value as a linear RGB value. If you are writing a value to an image in [an sRGB format](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Image_Format#sRGB_colorspace), then the system will interpret that value as *already being* in the sRGB colorspace. So no conversion will be performed; it will be written to the texture as-is. And if blending is active, the sRGB value you wrote will be blended against the sRGB value in the image, in the sRGB colorspace.

Now, when it comes to writing to an sRGB colorspace image, you usually don't want that behavior. If you have a linear RGB value, you want the system to convert that value to the sRGB colorspace (rather than pretending it already is). Equally importantly, when blending is active, you want the value in the sRGB image to be converted into linear RGB, then blended with the linear value written by the fragment shader, and finally converted back into sRGB. Otherwise, blending yields results of dubious accuracy.

To make all that happen, you [must `glEnable(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB)`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Framebuffer#Colorspace). When this feature is enabled, colorspace conversion happens for any fragment shader output written to any image whose colorspace is sRGB.

This value is disabled by default.

So if you want to write linear RGB values and have them converted to sRGB for display purposes, then you must:

1. Make sure that the framebuffer image you're writing to uses the sRGB colorspace. For FBOs, this is trivial. But if you're writing to the default framebuffer, then that's something you have to work out with your OpenGL initialization code.
2. Enable `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB` when you wish to use colorspace conversion.

Comment: "when blending is active, you want the value in the sRGB image to be converted into linear RGB, then blended with the linear value written by the fragment shader, and finally converted back into sRGB." - unless your target users are also Photoshop users in which case they will complain loudly that your blending is wrong if it's done in linear RGB. :-/

Comment: Thanks! I read the documentation, but it was very confusing. For example, I thought then when the framebuffer is in sRGB, I have to write in sRGB, and when it is linear, I can write linear.

Comment: Do you have any pointers in what I have to look for to find out how to make the default framebuffer (created by GLUT) be in sRGB? `glutInitDisplayMode` has a `GL_RGBA` option, but there's noting about linear or sRGB. I found out that I can use `glGetFramebufferAttachmentParameteriv(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_FRONT_LEFT, GL_FRAMEBUFFER_ATTACHMENT_COLOR_ENCODING)` to read this property, and it returns GL_LINEAR, but there seems to be no `glSetFramebufferAttachmentParameteriv`.

Comment: Alright, I just found that there is a constant `GLUT_SRGB`, but couldn't find any documentation how to use it either in the FreeGLUT or the original GLUT documentation.

Comment: @A.Donda: It's a parameter to `glutInitDisplayMode`. Also, you need to ask yourself a question: do you want to keep using a tool that is so poorly documented, or do you want to switch to something where the maintainers care enough to keep the documentation up-to-date, and therefore make the tool usable?

Comment: You're right. I started with GLUT because it was recommended for starting with OpenGL. Now I'm already using SDL2 for game controller input, so I probably should switch to SDL2 for graphics, too.

Comment: But for now: The correct way to do it in GLUT, if I want to write linear RGB and have it gamma corrected for the screen, would be to both use `GLUT_SRGB` in `glutInitDisplayMode` and call `glEnable(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB)` after context creation – right?

Comment: I changed my code to use SDL2, but the result is still confusing: I can request an sRGB framebuffer with `SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB_CAPABLE, 1)` and then set `glEnable(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB)`, and this makes the image lighter. However, `glEnable(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB)` has the same effect with `SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB_CAPABLE, 0)`.

Comment: And `glGetFramebufferAttachmentParameteriv(
    GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_FRONT_LEFT, GL_FRAMEBUFFER_ATTACHMENT_COLOR_ENCODING)` returns `GL_LINEAR` under all conditions.